# Numpy vectorizing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have this function `fs(i,j,dif`). It is easy to vectorize this function by doing 
`vfunc = np.vectorize(fs)`
The thing is, I want calculate the output of this function for

```
i=0, j=1,2,3,4,5, ...ysize-1

i=1, J=1,2,3,4,5, ...ysize-1

....
i=xsize-1,  j=1,2,3,4,5 ... ysize-1
```

For one value of `i`, there is no problem with `vfunc(0, np.arange(ysize), 0)   (dif=0)`

But I can't find out how to do it for all values of `i`.

The only way I manage to do it was

```
vfunc([[0],[1],[2],...[xsize-1]], np.arange(ysize), 0)
```

which is not feasible for a large xsize. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That last `i` is `np.arange(xsize)[:,None]`, a (xsjze,1) shape array.

Comment: Cool, then a reshape(xsize*ysize) does what I intend to obtain.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to take a look at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as follows. You want to know how to express the list `[[0],[1],[2],...[xsize-1]]` in terms of xsize? List comprehension does the job for you.
`[[0],[1],[2],...[xsize-1]]=[[i] for i in range(xsize)]`
The vectorize function can then be called as follows (for an example function  `fs`)

```
import numpy as np

xsize=10
ysize=15

def fs(i,j,dif):
    return i+j

np.vectorize(fs)([[i] for i in range(xsize)],np.arange(ysize),0)
```